# exim4/mail Usage Question

Tags: cron

I have a `bash` script (`daily.sh`) that runs daily as a `cron` job for user `pi`. Recently, I received an *email notification* on my RPi that an error had occurred in `daily.sh`. It turned out that this email notification was very useful, but I don't understand how this was "triggered" - i.e. what caused it to be sent??

***Some background may be useful or relevant:***
I've learned today that the `exim4` MTA on my RPi was installed months ago as a *Suggested Dependency* when the `at` utility was installed. `exim4` is not a *"default"* install - not part of the RPi OS Lite distro I use.

***The text of the emailed error message:***

> Date: Thu, 07 Jan 2021 06:00:32 -0600
> From: Cron Daemon root@raspberrypi4b.local
> To: pi@raspberrypi4b.local
> Subject: Cron pi@raspberrypi4b /home/pi/daily.sh 2 >> /home/pi/cron_error.log
>
> /home/pi/daily.sh: line 27: [: !=: unary operator expected

**I don't think this is relevant to my question, but I'll mention it "just in case":**
As it turns out, this error was not redirected to the `cron_error.log` because I mistakenly said, `2 >>` instead of `2>>` in my `crontab`.

I know that it's possible to declare the `MAILTO` variable in a `crontab` (i.e. `MAILTO=pi`), but there is no such declaration in the `crontab` for user `pi` (or any other user for that matter). AFAICT there is no default "global" declaration for `cron` either. Yet, somehow, `cron` knew to send this error message to the inbox for `pi`. How did that happen?

Comment: Cron runs stuff with /bin/sh (dash). That's the not same as /bin/bash and the syntax for unary operators is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a process started by crontab writes to stdout or stderr crontab sends an e-mail with that text to the local users (process owner) mail address **provided that** an MTA is installed and configured for local delivery.

If you had correctly redirected stderr to a file or `/dev/null` it should not send a mail, as it gets no output on the output channels.

You can also suppress emails with the

```
MAILTO=""
```

entry in the crontab file. But simply not using MAILTO="..." does not switch off mails.

I've searched the internet for a explanation from a more experienced (than me) english writer ;-).:  [here's one](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-the-mail-alert-by-crontab-command/)

Comment: Very good! I had missed the bit about the `MAILTO` variable being the **default**. It was in `man 5 crontab`, but TLDR :)  Adding to the confusion, the `exim4` MTA was broken sometime after I installed it with a faulty configuration setting for IPv6.